# Clicking on any single row in datagridview window vibrates all other controls in form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` that has some records.when i click on any row in the `datagridview` it vibrates other controls in the same window form.

e.g

if window form contains textboxs, labels, Datagridview and navigator control etc.when clicking on any row of datagridview, it vibrates textboxes, labels and navigator control for a second.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Are you doing anything within row select event ?

Comment: No, nothing with row select event.

Answer (score 0):

try adding extension method to `DataGridView` and set the `DoubleBufferred` property to `true`.

```
public static void DoubleBuffered(this DataGridView dgv, bool setting) 
{ 
    Type dgvType = dgv.GetType(); 
    PropertyInfo pi = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", 
          BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); 
    pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, null); 
}
```